# User permissions for TFS Build server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am creating a build using the new TFS 2015 Build definitions.  I have msbuild tasks as well as npm/gulp tasks.  I am looking at using variables to allow me to build and deploy to each environment, with DEV being the only one that runs on check-in.  However, I don't want anyone to be able to start a deploy for production.  How would I go about limiting the users that can start a deploy to production?  I'd prefer to only have one build definition, for maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Release hub capabilities for deployments and create an approval workflow for your environment pipeline.

Comment: Thanks.  I might have more questions related to this, but this is definitely what I needed.